# How to move my OmniFocus data from old Mac to new Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, data-transfer, migration, omnifocus

How can I move my data entered into OmniFocus 2.12 on macOS from my old computer (or hard drive) to my new computer (or hard drive)?

Should I just locate and move a data file? If so, where is that data file stored, in what folder?

I am not using Apple’s *Migration Assistant*. I want to do this move manually.

Comment: What version of OmniFocus are you running on your 'new' machine. [Omni Group Support](https://support.omnigroup.com/omnifocus/articles/) which should be your first stop.

Comment: @IconDaemon Same version of the app on both. I did check their site, and found [*Finding and reducing the size of your OmniFocus database*](https://support.omnigroup.com/reduce-size-omnifocus-database/). But that is not clear about migrating, nor does it explain where the data file is located.

Answer (score 4):

Quoth OmniGroup:

> The database file now is in a sandboxed container. The easiest way to get to the file is by opening the backup folder through 'File' → 'Show Backups…'. The data file is in the same folder as the Backups folder.

From: https://discourse.omnigroup.com/t/where-does-omnifocus-2-keep-the-database-file/4211/2